# Custom Button for generate apex class from wsdl

Tags: apex

I have no idea for this topic... My question is, it is possible to create a custom button for generate apex class from wsdl on visualforce page. Anyone known answer please help me for this..

Thank You

Comment: What i'm trying to ask, This is my qus

Comment: How can WSDL be parsed in Salesforce through custom code in apex without using ''GENERATE TO APEX BUTTON''.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way rathe than using the Generate From WSDL button?